# Where to enter these network configuration

Tags: networking, centos, ip, centos6

I have a dedicated server which I want to install CentOS 6.6 on.
The problem is:

The service provider gives me these:

```
Network: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx
Gateway: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Broadcast: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Mask: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Now I'm here: [My Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANM4y.png)

Where should I enter these ?

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/sn-Netconfig-x86.html#idp29757424

Comment: Thanks. But I asked it here because I don't know the meanings of the words I mentioned and where should I enter them inside this window ... as I'm a newbie ... and needed to repartition my server but have to configure my network manually too but I have low knowledge of netwoking

Comment: You can restart the installation in a different language if it is helpful to you. You can also change the language of the documentation at the top of the page.

Comment: I didn't mean that ... I meant there is no filed named network and broadcast ... and I don't know where to enter them

Comment: "Network" and "Broadcast" are not used here. You do not need to enter them, since they are calculated values anyway.

Comment: But the support told me I have to enter all these manually ... are you sure ?

Comment: You mean I should just enter gateway as gateway ... server as adress ... mask as subbent mask ? And it's enough ?

Comment: Right, that's all you need to do there. But you also need a DNS server address, and they don't seem to have supplied that to you?

Comment: No ... and I think it must be one of these ... or not ?

Comment: If your service provider doesn't give you a DNS server, you can use [Google's public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using).

Comment: When attaching a domain does it make any problems ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should put those information to `addresses` box via button `add`. There will be box where you insert IP address of server (this is Server), netmask (Mask) and Gateway (Gateway). Network and broadcast can be ignoted at all.